# File protocol schema

Tags: java, file-io, file-uri

I have path to local directory:

`String myPath = "C:\install"`;

I need to pass this path to method in third-party library. Third-party use path to directory in following ways:

```
File f = new File(s);
URL u = f.toURL();
```

and

```
new MyObject("file://" + myPath);
```

If it simply "C:\install", then I get exception while executing second pice of code (`MyObject`) - there is only 2 slashes instead 3. But if I add one slash to beginning of the string: "\C:\install", then second pice of code executes correctly, but `File#toURL();` converts it to `file:/C:/install`  - i.e. it ignores slash at the beginning..

Comment: `"file:///C:/install"` or `new File(myPath).toURI().toURL().getPath()`.

Comment: @JoopEggen hmmm. I think it wouldn't work because code in third-party lib explicitly adds `file://` string in addition to string which I pass. I.e. it will result to `"file://" +  "file:///C:/install"`